# rspec let with response.body returns empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Suppose I've got following code:

```
describe SomeController do
  let!(:body) { response.body }
  let(:body_parsed) { JSON.parse(response.body) }

  describe '#method' do
    before { post :create, some_params ; puts body; puts response.body }
    it { expect(body).to contain 'nice_stuff' }
  end
end
```

I would like to obtain `response.body` by `body`, but I am receiving empty string instead of excepted body. Additionally, when I print `body_parsed` it is printed fine. Are there any limitations for `response.body` with that approach?

Comment: Why would you expect `body` to be ever defined? Use `response.body` like this: `it { expect(response.body).to contain 'nice_stuff' }`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I can do this, and code I have written might be a bad habit, but I was just guessing why it is not working.

Comment: It is not working because **`let`** assignment is evaluated **when invoked**, while banged version **`let!`** is evaluated **when defined**. Get rid of exclamation sign and you are done.

Comment: Geez, you are definitely right. I should investigate for such informations deeper. Thanks a lot.